Having difficulty with Amazon Connect API(boto3) for python when trying to use the get-metric-data-v2
According to the API document I thought I had the filters and metrics fields set correctly, but getting errors when trying to run the following code:
import boto3
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
 
# Configuration
aws_region = 'us-west-2'  # AWS region
connect_instance_id = 'cso-success'  # Replace with your Amazon Connect instance ID
start_time = datetime.now() - pd.DateOffset(days=1)  # Start time for metrics
end_time = datetime.now()  # End time for metrics
 
# Initialize Amazon Connect client
client = boto3.client('connect', region_name=aws_region)
 
# Function to retrieve metrics data from Amazon Connect
def get_metrics_data(instance_id, start_time, end_time):
    response = client.get_metric_data_v2(
        ResourceArn=instance_id,
  StartTime=start_time,
        EndTime=end_time,
        Filters=[{'FilterKey': 'QUEUE','FilterValues': [ 'agentPerformance' ] }],
        Metrics=[{'Name':'AVG_HANDLE_TIME', 'Threshold': [{'SUM_ONLINE_TIME_AGENT'],  # Add more metrics as needed
        Groupings=['QUEUE']
    )
    return response['MetricResults']

# Main script
def main():
    metrics_data = get_metrics_data(connect_instance_id, start_time, end_time)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`

I have been trying to decipher the aws documentation, but cant figure out what is actually wrong since they don't even give valid examples anywhere and searching gives nothing.  Any help is appreciated.
Fairly new to python so may have issues with that too since not sure on coding structure.
I have tried using chatgpt to find instructions on format of filter and metrics.  I have scoured aws connect api documentation to find it is using a type of amazon.
I found this on a reference for boto3 as a definition:
response = client.get_metric_data_v2(ResourceArn='string',StartTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),EndTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),Filters=[{'FilterKey': 'string','FilterValues': ['string',]},],Groupings=['string',],Metrics=[{'Name': 'string','Threshold': [{'Comparison': 'string','ThresholdValue': 123.0},],'MetricFilters': [{'MetricFilterKey': 'string','MetricFilterValues': ['string',]},]},],NextToken='string',MaxResults=123)

Filters (list) –
[REQUIRED]
The filters to apply to returned metrics. You can filter on the following resources:

    •   Queues
    •   Routing profiles
    •   Agents
    •   Channels
    •   User hierarchy groups
    •   Filter keys : A maximum of 5 filter keys are supported in a single request. Valid filter keys: QUEUE | ROUTING_PROFILE | AGENT | CHANNEL | AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_ONE | AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_TWO | AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_THREE | AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_FOUR | AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_FIVE
    •   Filter values : A maximum of 100 filter values are supported in a single request. For example, a GetMetricDataV2 request can filter by 50 queues, 35 agents, and 15 routing profiles for a total of 100 filter values. VOICE , CHAT , and TASK are valid filterValue for the CHANNEL filter key.
    •   (dict) –

Contains the filter to apply when retrieving metrics with the GetMetricDataV2 API.
◦   FilterKey (string) –
The key to use for filtering data. For example, QUEUE , ROUTING_PROFILE, AGENT , CHANNEL , AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_ONE , AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_TWO , AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_THREE , AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_FOUR , AGENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL_FIVE . There must be at least 1 key and a maximum 5 keys.
◦   FilterValues (list) –
The identifiers to use for filtering data. For example, if you have a filter key of QUEUE , you would add queue IDs or ARNs in FilterValues .
▪   (string) –

